# rust / cargo workspace: how to specify different profile for different sub project

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a rust Cargo workspace that contains different subproject:

```
./
├─Cargo.toml
├─project1/
│ ├─Cargo.toml
│ ├─src/
├─project2/
│ ├─Cargo.toml
│ ├─src/
```

I would like to build one project optimized for binary size and the other for speed.

From my understanding we can tweak the profiles only at the cargo.toml root level so this for instance applies to all my sub-projects.

root Cargo.toml:

```ini
[workspace]
members = ["project1", "project2"]

[profile.release]
# less code to include into binary
panic = 'abort'
# optimization over all codebase ( better optimization, slower build )
codegen-units = 1
# optimization for size ( more aggressive )
opt-level = 'z'
# optimization for size
# opt-level = 's'
# link time optimization using using whole-program analysis
lto = true
```

If I try to apply this configuration in a sub Cargo.toml it doesn't work

Question: is there a way to configure each project independently ?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: Also I forgot to say but one project is build with trunk and is a wasm project (I want to be the smaller possible) the other is a backend and I really need it to be built for speed

Comment: Did you get this error when you tried: `warning: profiles for the non root package will be ignored, specify profiles at the workspace root: package:   /home/jeremy/root/projectN/Cargo.toml workspace: /home/jeremy/root/Cargo.toml`? Also, I would be very surprised if you noticed a difference between optimization levels for most usecases.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows yes I got this error.

Also the size matter to me as one of this project is targeted for wasm and i observe a reduction in binary size from about 1.7Mo to 0.5Mo and that is not negligible when downloading it :)

Comment: The error says that you can't set different profiles for individual crates in a workspace, so you should just set `opt-level = s` at the root.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows this is precisely what i would like to avoid because the other project in my use case should be optimized for the most speed possible.

So far what i did is 
- build the project1 without the profile.release part in the root Cargo 
- then manually add my profile configuration optimized for size 
- finally build project2 and that is a bit of a pain ^^

Comment: Maybe you could precompile to a `.o` with your flags set then have Cargo link those versions? I've never tried that, but just a suggestion.

Comment: I'll definitively look at your suggestion :)

Answer (score 4):

Each crate in a workspace can have its own `.cargo/config.toml` where different profiles [can be defined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html). I've toyed around with this a bit to have one crate for an embedded device, one for a CLI utility to connect to the device over serial, and shared libraries for both of them. Pay attention to the caveat in the docs about needing to be in the crate directory for the config to be read, it won't work from the workspace root.